# jQuery/DOM does not update viewport after changing sizes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In a DIV I have inserted images that I always want to display in 60% width of the **original size** of the image file (so that the images are on the same scale). For this I use the following jQuery-Script:

```
var cont_slider_ori_width;
var cont_slider_ori_height;

$('.img-drawing').each(function(i) {

    var img = $(this);

    $("<img>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src")).load(function() {
        cont_slider_ori_width = this.width;   // to get the original width of the image-file
        cont_slider_ori_height = this.height; // to get the original height of the image-file
    });

    img.width(cont_slider_ori_width * 0.6);

    // alert($(this).attr('src'));  // If I avtivate this alert command, the size-changes work as it should ...

});
```

The HTML-Markup:

```
<div class="cont-slider-item-img-wrapper">

    <div class="cont-slider-item-drw">
        <img class="img-drawing" src="image1.png" alt="" width="1042" height="412">
    </div>

    <div class="cont-slider-item-drw">
        <img class="img-drawing" src="image2.png" alt="" width="1042" height="411">
    </div>

</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.cont-slider-item-img-wrapper {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;

   .cont-slider-item-drw {

      img {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }

    }

}
```

But unfortunately this does not work (the size is not changed). It's strange that when I activate the 'alert' command, the redraw for the respective elements works as expected after each confirmation of the alarm box.

What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: You're randomly using `$(this)`, `$(img)` and `$("img")` in your code, maybe start there. You can also get the original width using `$(this).get()[0].naturalWidth` afaik.

Comment: Thank you very much! :-) That solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

With the friendly help of Chris G (see comments above) I was able to solve the problem. This is the jQuery/Javascript code, which is working now:

```
var cont_slider_ori_width;
var cont_slider_ori_height;

$('.img-drawing').each(function(i) {

    cont_slider_ori_width = $(this).get()[0].naturalWidth;
    $(this).width(cont_slider_ori_width * 0.6);

});
```